# Error: Unknown Content-Encoding- PHP consumiendo WSDL con SoapClient

Tags: php, soap

Tengo este problema al tratar de consumir un web service wsdl:

> Unknown Content-Encoding

He tratado comprimiéndolo en GZIP mandándole el charset, pero al momento de ejecutar me da dicho error.

El código en php para este consumo es el siguiente:

```
$usuario="user1";
$location_URL = "https://www.txstestrbm.com/GlobalPayServicios/GlobalPayServicioDePago";
$pass="abc123";
$wsdl="https://www.pagosrbm.com/GlobalPayServicios/GlobalPayServicioDePago/GlobalPayServicioDePago.wsdl";
$mode = array (
    'soap_version'  => 'SOAP_1_1', // use soap 1.1 client
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => 1,
    'encoding'      => utf-8,
    'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
    'Content-Encoding'=> 'UTF-8',
    'exceptions'    => true,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
);
$options = array(
    'trace'=>true,
    'location' => $location_URL,
    'credenciales' => array(
        'idUsuario'    => $usuario,
        'clave' => $pass
    ),
    'cabeceraSolicitud' =>array(
        'infoPuntoInteraccion'=> array(
            'tipoTerminal'=> 'GlobalPay',
            'idTerminal'=>'ESB10457',
            'idAdquiriente'=>'0014591978',
            'idTransaccionTerminal'=>'0101'
        )
    ),
    'infoCompra' => array(
        'numeroFactura' => '',
        'montoTotal' => '',
        'infoImpuestos' => array(
            'tipoImpuesto'=>'iva',   
            'monto' =>'0'
        ),
        'montoDetallado' => array(
           'tipoMontoDetallado'=>'precio',
           'monto'=> '10000'
        ),
    ),
);

try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $mode);  
    $data = $soap->IniciarTransaccionDeCompra($options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
var_dump($data);
die;
```

La página la pueden consultar [aquí](http://demo.samaneo.com.co/index.php?controller=rbm-pago). Le agradecería a alguien si me puede ayudar con este error.

Comment: amigo, encontraste solucion? estoy en las mismas, con un codigo parecido, tratando de implementar el boton de rdb.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding debe ir dentro de comillas:

```
  'encoding'      => utf-8,
```

Cambia a:

```
  'encoding'      =>'UTF-8',
```

Por esa razón no detecta el encoding.

- Asegura también configurar dentro de tu `php.ini` :

**zlib.output_compression = On**

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder y sacar de tu tiempo. ya lo cambie pero me sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: Diego, realiza una prueba únicamente con : "compression" => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT) y dime que resultado tienes.

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo por responder estoy indicando esto, $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("compression" => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));

Me retorna el mismo resultado.

Comment: ;soap
extension=php_soap.dll

;zip
zlib.output_compression = On

Esta habilitado la opcion

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en en que no estás conectándote al *TLSv1.2*, y no usas los certificados unos archivos *.cert*, que debieron darte, para llamar el servicio. Ademas, esa *url* no es la que debes usar para pruebas, usa el archivo *wsdl*, debes subirlo al servidor y ponerlo al lado. Esto completa bien la cabecera del mensaje *soap* `'local_cert' => 'www.txstestrbm.com.cer'`, es lo mas importante, luego debes hacer 10 casos de uso y enviarlos para que te den los certificados originales. Pienso que debes comunicarte con las personas del botón o probarlo por *soap UI*, y si funciona, luego envías un *payload*, y listo.